# Recycler view goes null on switching fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a recycler view to show some items, everything works fine but when I open another fragment and then reopen the fragment having `recyclerview`. it doesn't show anything.

Can somebody tell me what is its cause?

Comment: This must be the issue with fragment life cycle. You are not using the fragment life cycle methods perfectly. Post your code for a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the lifecycle of a fragment.
It seems your code for filling the recyclerview with data is in the wrong method.

Lifecycle methods like `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()` etc. are just called on creating the fragment.

if you leave the fragment (and do not `finish()` it by yourself), it won't be destroyed so these methods are not called again.

You need to fill your recycler view in `onResume()` method